# Powershell Copy-Item Not going to destination

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm running the below PS to move files from one directory to another. The issue I'm having is that it does not copy the items to the destination, it copies them to the directory I'm calling the script from. The destination is a file share that I've mapped.

```
$originalPath1 = "C:\Source\Source\"
$targetFile1 = "Q:\destination\"

Get-ChildItem $originalPath1\* -Include  *.xxx, *.yyy, *.ddd, *.eee, *.ttt |
   ForEach-Object{ $targetFile1 = $htmPath + $_.FullName.SubString($originalPath1.Length);
 New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile1 -Force;
 Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile1 }
```

Comment: Don't want to move the files, just copy them. Poor mans backup here.

Comment: What is `$htmPath` ? Are you trying to copy the file to the destination folder **including** the original's file folder structure?

Comment: The source of this script came from a few posts. I'm not sure what the $htmPath is for. The copy does not include any folders, just files.

Comment: If you don't want to replicate the original files folder structure, you will probably end up with naming collisions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'poor mans backup', you could use below code to copy the files that match the pattern to a destination folder.

This will also create the subfolder structure the original file was in:

```
$originalPath = 'C:\Source\Source'
$destination  = 'Q:\destination'
$includeThese = '*.xxx', '*.yyy', '*.ddd', '*.eee', '*.ttt'

Get-ChildItem -Path $originalPath -File -Recurse -Include $includeThese |
ForEach-Object {
    # create the destination folder
    $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($originalPath.Length)
    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target -Force
    # copy the file to the target path
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Works as expected!